What to do if malloc() returns a valid pointer, but sets errno to non-zero?
In Microsoft's documentation for malloc(), there are the following two statements:
In section "Return value":

malloc returns a void pointer to the allocated space, or NULL if there's insufficient memory available. [...]

In section "Remarks":

malloc sets errno to ENOMEM if a memory allocation fails or [...]

The wording in the two citations implies that malloc() can fail due to other reasons than insufficient memory. Therefore, it is possible that malloc() returns a valid pointer (i.e., returns non-NULL), but at the same time sets errno to a non-zero value.
My question is what we should do in that situation:
On one hand, we have got a valid pointer that we should free() later to avoid resource leaks. On the other hand, despite the valid pointer, malloc() obviously had a problem actually allocating the requested memory, so freeing the pointer later might be a bad idea.
Can somebody shed some light on this?

Have you actually observed such a thing happening?  Code or it didn't happen.

I'd argue that the wording under "Return value" is too colloquial in that it assumes that insufficient memory is the only reason why malloc can fail. It would better be said that "... or NULL if memory allocation fails".

@Binarus Does malloc(0) return NULL and/or sets errno on your machine?

On select systems, malloc() can fail due to too many allocations and not out-of-memory (i.e. lots of small ones).

"it is possible that malloc() returns a valid pointer (i.e., returns non-NULL), but at the same time sets errno to a non-zero value." --> this I doubt.

If malloc returns a non-NULL pointer, then the memory allocation succeeded, and I wouldn't expect errno to be set.  People don't normally check errno unless malloc returns NULL, in which case memory allocation failed (ignoring the case where a size of 0 is requested).

According to POSIX man page: The value of errno should only be examined when it is indicated to be valid by a function's return value. More specifically in Linux man page: The value in errno is significant only when the return value of the call indicated an error (i.e., -1 from most system calls; -1 or NULL from most library functions); a function that succeeds is allowed to change errno. The value of errno is never set to zero by any system call or library function.

errno is not modified except on error conditions. The proper sequence of events, should you wish to examine it, is: ❶ set errno to zero; ❷ attempt to malloc(); ❸ only if the result of malloc() is NULL then ❹ examine errno.

@Binarus There is clear written in the C Standard: " If the space cannot be allocated, a null pointer is returned".

Nit: You claim it can return a valid pointer on failure. But returning a valid pointer is the very definition of success, so that's nonsense. It must necessarily return NULL or an invalid pointer on failure. (It never does, and that would be contrary to the C standard, but that should be your argument.)

@Dúthomhas errno is not modified except on error conditions Yes it can be: "The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of errno is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard."  malloc() is not documented in the C standard to set errno, so it's free to change errno in non-error conditions.

@MikeNakis and chux: Regarding your "Did it actually happen" question: No, it didn't. But this question is completely irrelevant to me. I have neither the time nor the motivation to test every of the thousands of Windows API functions regarding their conformance to standards, their correct documentation or their correct behavior. I am an ordinary mortal and have to completely rely on the documentation for each function. After all, it is the key point of an API documentation that we can rely on it and that we don't need to find out ourselves how a function works and handles errors.

@j6t Thank you for wording it that way. That's exactly what I meant.

@TomKarzes Thanks for your comment. If malloc returns a non-NULL pointer, then the memory allocation succeeded, and I wouldn't expect errno to be set. I wouldn't expect that, too. However, expectation is a dangerous thing in the field of programming, especially when documentation leaves room for an interpretation that contradicts the expectation.

@dimich Thank you very for your comment. I now have to research whether and to which extent the Windows API conforms to Posix. I don't know anything about this yet. Your comment was enlightening, because Microsoft did its own thing and didn't care about standards in many areas, so I wouldn't have come to the idea to look up Windows malloc()'s behavior in a Posix man page. If the latter is a valid approach, it makes life a lot easier, because there are more API functions with similar problems in the documentation, and it would be nice to look up the others in the Posix man pages, too.

@dimich For the sake of completeness: The passages you have cited do not tell the full truth either. For example, there are important API functions that do not return a value at all, but set errno in case of problems. A prominent example is free(). Obviously, we cannot use the return value of such functions to decide if we should check errno.

@Dúthomhas Thanks for explaining. That's how I would have expected it to work, and is the method I have applied during the last decades. But recently I saw Microsoft's malloc() documentation which seems to contradict Posix documentation, introducing ambiguity, which made me worry. Since I don't know the relationship between the Windows API and Posix, I thought that Microsoft might have its own interpretation of how malloc() should behave. The next thing I'll do is to research that relationship.

@VladfromMoscow Thank you very much. IMHO, that's the most convincing statement among the comments so far. If you make an answer from your comment, ideally with a link to the respective part of the standard, I'll accept it.

@ikegami Nit: You claim it can return a valid pointer on failure. But returning a valid pointer is the very definition of success, so that's nonsense. First, it's not me who claims that; it's the wording of Microsoft's documentation that leaves room for this interpretation if we take it literally. Second, I did not write "on failure". Rather, my question was about a non-NULL return value in conjunction with errno being set. Actually, it was the point of the question whether or not we should treat this situation as a failure and how we should react to it.

@chux On select systems, malloc() can fail due to too many allocations and not out-of-memory (i.e. lots of small ones). Thanks for explaining it that clearly. So malloc() can indeed return non-NULL, but set errno nevertheless. --> this I doubt. I doubt it, too, and have only checked malloc()'s return value during the last 30 years. Until I saw that part of the Microsoft documentation ...

@Binarus free() can not "fail". In C, The behavior is undefined if the value of ptr does not equal a value returned earlier by malloc(), calloc(), realloc(), or aligned_alloc(). The behavior is undefined if the memory area referred to by ptr has already been deallocated. If malloc() failed, it doesn't return value. If it didn't fail, free() always succeed. If you pass to free() something other than returned by allocator or already freed pointer - it's UB.

@Binarus  In some implementations (including glibc before 2.33) free() may change errno, but it should not interfere with your program. Just don't check errno after free(). Since glibc-2.33 The free() function returns no value, and preserves errno..

@Binarus There are functions where failure is not distinguishable just by return value. But since the value of errno is never set to zero by any system call or library function, you can set errno=0 before call and check it if some special value (often NULL) returned. For example, in readdir(): To distinguish end of stream from an error, set errno to zero before calling readdir() and then check the value of errno if NULL is returned.

@Binarus I have to believe the documentation, whether or not the behavior it describes is sensible. Keep in mind that the documentation you are citing is a community effort. Do not expect that it was written by the very software engineers that implemented this particular malloc, and, even if they wrote the documentation and were great engineers, that they are great in expressing their thoughts. Apply common sense, and if in doubt, look at the source code; it is available.

@dimich, Re "But since the value of errno is never set to zero by any system call or library function", You're quoting the POSIX documentation, which doesn't apply here. Windows isn't a POSIX system.

Re "First, it's not me who claims that; it's the wording of Microsoft's documentation that leaves room for this interpretation", No it doesn't. Again, it's impossible by definition. If it returns a valid pointer, it succeeded at allocating memory by definition, and that means it didn't fail. That means it can only possibly return an invalid pointer on failure. (And the C standard further restricts it to NULL.)

@ikegami I'm quoting POSIX because readdir() is POSIX function. If Windows isn't a POSIX system, don't use POSIX functions in Windows. Use FindFirstFile()/FindNextFile() and GetLastError().

The full sentence you partially quoted is:

malloc sets errno to ENOMEM if a memory allocation fails or if the amount of memory requested exceeds _HEAP_MAXREQ.

Reading this, I have little doubt that in the latter case, malloc will return a null pointer, and you can test this hypothesis with malloc(_HEAP_MAXREQ+1), provided _HEAP_MAXREQ is less than SIZE_MAX.
The memory allocation failure the documentation refers to is the subtask of allocating memory from the operating system. Either reason for failure, a failure to allocate memory from the system or exceeding the limit on how much may be requested, means the requested memory is not available and results in returning a null pointer, as stated in “malloc returns… NULL if there's insufficient memory available.”
Additionally, setting errno to a non-zero value does not indicate an error. C 2018 7.5 3 says:

… The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of errno is not documented in the description of the function in this document.

And the documentation for malloc does not mention errno.
So the way you determine whether malloc failed or not is by determining whether its return value is a null pointer or not.

This is a classic function design problem.
Code does 2 things:  returns a pointer and maybe sets errno.  Are these outputs tied or independent?

Documentation implies:

Valid pointer returned and errno not changed.
NULL returned and errno changed.
Documentation is not pedantically clear that other cases are possible or not.

Simply takes this as a very slight lack of clarification on case 3.  Case 3 does not happened.

Call free(x) once on each non-NULL pointer from malloc().
Since free(NULL) is OK, one could call free(x) once on every pointer from malloc().
Note that per the C spec, malloc() is not required to set errno.  Portable code only uses the pointer returned for success determination.

This is also caused by an assumed understanding of the problem being solved. Since there's only one error return value (NULL), any additional information has to be passed out-of-band. The mechanism for that is errno. And you can't check errno when a non-NULL value is returned, because in that case you couldn't even tell which function did set errno. Hence, we can reason why case 3 cannot exist.

IMO: malloc returning a non NULL value and modifying errno is most likely UB as a consequence of a messed up heap due to prior illegal modifying of non owned memory.

@Jabberwocky Agree'd - some sort of UB.  For my part, I do not care about errno with malloc() as the C spec does not require setting it under any condition.

Implementation of malloc could attempt to acquire a large enough block of previously freed memory. This fails because no such block exists and sets errno. Code then allocates a new block and returns valid pointer.  No UB, but errno set.

malloc is not enforced to touch errno in case of no error.  This includes successful execution.  (this means that you could have received some previous error which is not reset by malloc.

malloc returns a void pointer to the allocated space, or NULL if there's insufficient memory available. [...]

must be interpreted as or else NULL if there's insufficient memory.  So, only if malloc() returns NULL you should check errno.
